# myFaces Trinidad example not displaying

Tags: jsf, richfaces, myfaces, trinidad

Hi I have followed the setup guide at:
http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/installation.html

When I include the following code in my faces-config.xml file I get an error when I hit a page:

```
<application>
        <default-render-kit-id>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.core</default-render-kit-id>
    </application>
```

Start of Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No RenderingContext
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeBegin(CoreRenderer.java:390)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.htmlBasic.HtmlFormRenderer.encodeBegin(HtmlFormRenderer.java:56)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:813)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:928)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:933)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:592)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
```

When I remove that piece of code from my faces-config.xml file I can navigate my site as normal, but when I hit a page that has some sample Trinidad code nothing is displayed...just an empty page.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

I removed the following from my web.xml and its working now, any ideas? Confused :(

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.VIEW_HANDLERS</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be mixing RichFaces with Trinidad. I do neither, but from what I've read is that *in general* mixing completely different ajaxical component libraries won't always work very well because the view handlers may collide with each other. What does Trinidad offer for you which RichFaces doesn't? Why would you use them together?

Comment: I'm looking for a tree like table structure to maintain paginated pages of checkboxes: http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/tagdoc/tr_treeTable.html

An example can be see here (Giant Tree table): http://www.irian.at/trinidad-demo/faces/components/treeTable.jspx

Richfaces currently does not offer anything like this (I want to avoid customising components as much as possible).

Comment: What are you trying to do with me?! =)

Comment: I'm trying to use you to make a table Trinidad! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually discovered an excellent control for Richfaces that will provide the same functionailty. I'm going to go with this instead.

http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/extendedDataTable.jsf?c=extendedDataTable&tab=usage

As BalsusC suggested, mixing different ajaxical component libraries might not be such a good idea.

Additionally, I have found the documentation and examples for Trinidad to be quite poor; Particularly in comparasion to Richfaces.

Would I be correct in thinking Trinidad is slowly dying?